# Intuitive Rosenbrock's Valley/Banana Function.

Tags: optimization

The following is called **Rosenbrock's valley** or **Rosenbrock's Banana Function**,

$$f(x,y) = (1-x)^2+A(y-x^2)^2, \qquad (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$$

Can you explain **intuitively** why is this function so important in the study of Optimization?

What is so special about this function that makes it so interesting in the study of Optimization?

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, what do you think?

Comment: That the Wikipedia explains everything.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, **Yes**. I also have at least 10 Optimization e-books in my PC's hard drive. So, what do you think is the point of asking this question?

Comment: Asking for an "intuitive" explanation sounds a bit unreasonable in this case, unless you can somehow ask [Rosenbrock](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/3.3.175) himself. At the very least, he does say in his article that it helped him develop his own minimization method.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function) has a nice picture and explanation:

> The global minimum is inside a long, narrow, parabolic shaped flat valley. To find the valley is trivial. To converge to the global minimum, however, is difficult.

Solving for the minimizer analytically is easy: $f$ is minimized at $(1,1)$.

However, if $A$ is large, optimization algorithms might pay a lot of attention to the second term $(y-x^2)^2$ and find the "parabolic valley" $\{(x,y) : y=x^2\}$ easily, but will have trouble going along the valley (which is relatively flat) to find the minimizer $(1,1)$.